# How do I access radius control in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

I am trying to increase the radius of a graphic in Sketch.

However, the slider control for Radius is not appearing.

What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: I don't use Sketch, so this is only a guess, but it looks like the radius is coming from the actual image, and not a program setting.  This settings look like settings for importing a raster image, to change the corner radius, you would probably need to do something after you place the graphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use radius, that element should be a shape.

You most probably are trying to give radius properties to the group selection (`FR` in your example). This is not possible directly. For group of selection, you can use `Mask` option.

For this, expand your group. If it is an image, just add a rectangle under the image and right click on it and select `Mask`. Then you will be able to change radius by changing rectangle radius property as you want.

[image]